# Always show click-count

Tags: html, web, button

I have been trying to create a like counter for a webpage. Currently, It only shows the number likes when someone presses the button. The code is written below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =localStorage.clickcount;
    } 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button"  style="background-image:url(URL TAKEN OUT DUE TO COPYRIGHT ISSUE); background-position:left; background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:30px; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px; padding-right:4px" > Please Like! </button> </p>
<div id="result"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

I am aware that `.innerHTML` is the problem behind 'the number of likes' not being shown but I am not sure how to make it so that it always displayed and centred above the button.

Eg. If the page has 143 likes.

```
    143 
Please Like!
```

Please help me out - Thank You so much for reading

Comment: You want to show the likes as soon as the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes - all the previous accumulated likes must always be on display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to display the counter initially, and then keep track each time it changes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        showCounter();
    } 
}
function showCounter(){
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =localStorage.clickcount;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button"  style="background-image:url(URL TAKEN OUT DUE TO COPYRIGHT ISSUE); background-position:left; background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:30px; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px; padding-right:4px" > Please Like! </button> </p>
<div id="result"></div>


<script>
   showCounter(); //Fisrt call, Once the page is loaded.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also do <body onload='showCounter()' > and avoid second script tag. Cheers!